# Model Checking : Bad Prefixes using NFA

Tags: logic, state, nfa, model-checking

We use NFA to model BadPrefixes for the safety property.I want to understand for a given Safety property , how to model the NFA.

The following images are for reference.
[image]

[image]

[image]

For instance, for safety property P2 ,Can someone explain how to know how many states are required(solution has 4) and which logic to use on the edges, how in Fig.,3 and Fig.4 , the edges are selected to satisfy the badprefixes P1 and P2.Thanks.

Comment: This isn't notation I've seen for NFAs before. Looks like a blend of logic and automata? Can you elaborate on how to get from the description `P1` to the diagram `NFA1` (if those even correspond)? And also how do you interpret what `NFA1` and `NFA2` are doing? What does it mean for a state to point to itself on `true`? What exactly is your question with the above?

Comment: Take P2 for example , I have to create a NFA which does not satisfy this property .So one way would be qo - -(a) ->q1--(~b)->q2--(a)->q3.On edge 'a' qo moves to q1 state.So this NFA does not satisfy this property because between two 'a' there is no 'b'.'true' corresponds to all possible combinations of AP = {a,b,c}set.It can be{{a},{b},{c},{ab},{bc},{ca},{a,b,c},{emptysymbol}}

Comment: @GopalaKrishna can you share from where you got these NFAs Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have several definitions and notations here, let's go through these first:

- We are given a set of atomic propositions AP. It is not said here explicitly, but usually this means we are interested in languages that have as alphabet the power set of AP. So for AP = {a,b,c}, our alphabet would be Sigma = { {}, {a}, {b}, {c}, {a,b}, {a,c}, {b,c}, {a,b,c} }.
- As you can see, writing out this power set alphabet can be a lot of work. For this reason, there is an alternative notation based on propositional formulas. Consider a propositional formula phi over the variables AP. We can take a symbol x from Sigma and in phi set all atomic propositions contained in x to true and all other atomic propositions to false. Then we evaluate phi and it becomes true or false. We can understand phi to refer to all those x from Sigma for which phi evaluates to true.

  For example, the formula phi="a and not b" refers to the symbols {a} and {a,c}. The formula phi="a" refers to the symbols {a},{a,b},{a,c},{a,b,c}. The formula phi="not a" refers to the symbols {},{b},{c},{b,c}. The formula phi="not a and not b and not c" refers only to the symbol {}. The formula phi="true" refers to all symbols from Sigma. The formula phi="false" refers to no symbol (not to be confused with the symbol {}). And so on ...

  This logic is the notation used on the NFA edges in your example.
- We call a language L over finite words "regular" if there is a NFA that accepts L.
- We call a language L over infinite traces a "safety property" if every trace not in L has a bad prefix, meaning a finite prefix w, such that no infinite continuation of w is in L.
- We call a safety property "regular" if the language of its bad prefixes is regular. Note we are dealing with two different notions of "regular" here, one for languages of finite words and one for safety properties over infinite traces.

### General approach

You are dealing with the problem of going from an informal description of a safety property to a formal description of the language of its bad prefixes. There is no general rule for how to do this, but remember that on an intuitive level, a safety property means "some bad event never happens". The language of the bad prefixes is then exactly those finite words for which "the bad event happens at some point". Your approach would therefore be to analyze what the "bad event" is.

(This is a general problem in model checking of course, when going from informal descriptions to a formal model there is a risk of not perfectly capturing the original description.)

Consider P1: The bad event is "a becomes valid and afterwards b is valid only finitely many steps and becomes false before c becomes true". We can turn this into a slightly more verbose description: "a becomes valid, afterwards we see some b's but no c's and then we see no b and no c". We can use this description to derive a formal definition for "the bad event happens at some point". I personally find regular expressions more intuitive than NFAs, so I would first try to build a regular expression and then build the NFA from that afterwards:

```
(true)* a (b and not c)* (not b and not c) (true)*
```

This regular expression describes all finite words where at some point the bad event happens. We use the (true)* at the beginnging and the end because we do not care what happens before or after the bad event. The regular expression is already very close the NFA in your example, in general it should be easy to build NFAs from such regular expressions. You can see that the notation based on propositional formulas makes this much more compact compared to writing out the symbols explicitly, e.g. writing "a" is shorter than writing the full regular expression ({a} + {a,b} + {a,c} + {a,b,c}).

This is not the only solution, instead of requiring to see (b and not c)* before seeing (not b and not c), it would also suffice to require to see (not c)* before seeing (not b and not c). This would result in the regular expression:

```
(true)* a (not c)* (not b and not c) (true)*
```

The only difference to the first solution would be that instead of requiring to match the first (not b and not c) we see, we could also skip over some (not b and not c)'s because they also match (not c), as long as we match a (not b and not c) eventually. So in a way the first solution is the better one because the resulting NFA is more deterministic.

Consider P2: The bad event would be having two a's such that in between at some point b does not hold. Turning this into a slightly more verbose description, we would get "we see a, afterwards we see some b's without seeing a, then we reach a point where we see neither b nor a, afterwards we see any symbols until we reach the closing a". Turning this into a regular expression for "the bad event happens at some point" gives us:

```
(true)* a (b and not a)* (not b and not a) (true)* a (true)*
```

Again this is very similar to the NFA in your example, it should be easy to see how to construct an NFA from such an expression. As before we could also obtain an alternative solution, by relaxing the (b and not a)* to (not a)*, the only difference would be that this would allow to skip over some (not b and not a), as long as we match one eventually. Also, we could strengthen the middle (true)* to (not a)*, requiring us to match the first closing a instead of allowing to skip over some a's before matching the closing a:

```
(true)* a (not a)* (not b and not a) (not a)* a (true)*
```

### Regarding the number of states

Since you asked about how to know the number of states: I would first try to obtain some NFA and then check if it can be simplified. For the NFAs in your example, I see no way to further reduce the number of states, but in general minimizing NFAs is a hard problem ([reference](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/10829/computing-the-minimal-nfa-for-a-dfa)), so there is no efficient algorithm for that. Of course, if you obtain a fully deterministic automaton, you can apply the standard algorithm for minimizing DFAs.

Comment: Perfect.Thanks for the answer. For P2 , can i write regular expression for bad prefix as   (true)* a (not a and not b)* a (true)*  ? If not, can you please why ?

Comment: No, because that regular expression would also match {a}{a} which is not a bad prefix, for example {a} {a} {}^omega would satisfy (P2). (P2) says that in between two a's, b has to always hold. If the two a's are directly adjacent, there are zero symbols in between, so all these symbols satisfy that b holds. To create a bad prefix, you need to ensure that in between the two a's, there is at least one (not b).

Comment: Then , going by that logic why `(true)* a (not a)* (not b and not a) (not a)* a (true)*`holds ? Does not `a(true)*` can be mapped to `aa{}` too ? Since true is the powerset over AP

Comment: `(true)* a (not a)* (not b and not a) (not a)* a (true)*` does not match `{a}{a}{}`, because to match the two `a`s in the expression, we would have to match `(true)* a` with the first `{a}` and then `a (true)*` with `{a}{}`. But then the middle `(not b and not a)` demands a symbol that contains no b and no a, but there is no such symbol in between `{a}` and `{a}{}`. On the other hand it would match `{a}{}{a}`, because you could match `(true)* a` with `{a}`, then `(not a)* (not b and not a)` with `{}` and finally `(not a)* a (true)*` with the closing `{a}`. Indeed, `{a}{}{a}` is a bad prefix.

Comment: Thanks,I have one more question.Suppose if the Property is "Every _a_ is followed by _b_ or _c_.Then the BadPref would be `(true)* a a* (true)*` .Can you please clarify ?

Comment: I assume "followed" is meant in the sense of "immediately after", not as "at some point after", which would not be a safety property. The bad prefixes would be those finite words where we read something, then `a`, then neither `b` nor `c`, and then again something. More formally `(true)* a (not b and not c) (true)*`. The expression `(true)* a a* (true)*` does not describe the bad prefixes. E.g. it matches `{a}{b}`, which is not a bad prefix: match `(true)*` with the empty word, `a` with `{a}`, `a*` with the empty word and `(true)*` with `b`. Recall that the `*` means zero or more repetitions.

Comment: But even if you took `(true)* a a+ (true)*`, with `a+` meaning one or more repetitions, it would not be correct: `a` is different from `not b and not c`. Recall `a` is short-hand for `{a}`,`{a,b}`,`{a,c}`,`{a,b,c}`, whereas `not b and not c` is short-hand for `{}`,`{a}`. So `(true)* a a+ (true)*` would match the word `{a} {a,b} {b}`, which also is not a bad prefix: Match `(true)*` with the empty word, `a` with `{a}`, `a+` with `{a,b}` and `(true)*` with `{b}`. But this word is not a bad prefix.

Comment: Yes, I meant immediately after .This makes sense. Suppose if the property are `P1 : Whenever a , then either b or c is also true` , `P2 : b until finally c ` and `P3: b holds only finitely often` and `P4 : b holds infinitely often`.Would these properties be termed Safety properties ? I think P2 and P3 are safety properties. Can you please clarify ?

Comment: P1: Yes. This is an invariant, meaning a property that specifies what individual symbols in the trace should look like, without considering their context, i.e. the symbols before or after. Every invariant is a safety property. The bad prefixes would be of the form "read something, then read a symbol that does not meet the invariant, then read something again". In this case "(true)* (a and not b and not c) (true*)".

Comment: P2: Depends on the meaning of "until". I'm assuming it means "eventually c and before that always b" (known as "strong until"), this is not a safety property. The infinite trace `{b}{b}{b} ...` has no bad prefix. Every finite prefix can be continued to a trace where P2 holds. E.g. `{b}` can be continued to `{b}{c}{}{}{} ...`, `{b}{b}` can be continued to `{b}{b}{c}{}{}{}...` and so on.

Comment: The alternative interpretation is "b holds forever or eventually c and before that always b" (known as "weak until"). This is a safety property. The bad prefixes are of the form `(b and not c)* (not b and not c) (true)*`. In your previous question we talked about closure. Think of weak-until as the closure of strong-until.

Comment: P3: Not a safety property. Consider the infinite trace `{b}{b}{b}...` which does not satisfy P3. This trace does not have a bad prefix. Every finite prefix can be continued to a trace in P3. E.g. `{b}` can be continued to `{b}{}{}{}...`, `{b}{b}` can be continued to `{b}{b}{}{}{}...` and so on.

Comment: P4: Not a safety property. Consider the trace `{}{}{}...` which does not satisfy P4. This trace does not have a bad prefix. Every finite prefix can be continued to a trace in P4. E.g. `{}` can be continued to `{}{b}{b}{b}...`, `{}{}` can be continued to
`{}{}{b}{b}{b}...`and so on.

Comment: Your general approach would be: If you think something is a safety property, identify what the bad prefixes look like. For all traces that do not meet the property, check if the trace has some position where no matter how the trace goes on, you know the property can never be satisfied (the bad event has happened). If you think something is not a safety property, try to find a trace not satisfying the property that does not have a bad prefix. I.e. a trace where every position on the trace allows some alternative continuation that satisfies the property (you never reach an irrecoverable pos.).

Comment: Hi bro, For P2 , can i write regular expression for bad prefix as `(true)* a (not a and not b) a (true)* `? Why `(b and not a)* and  (true)*` are needed? Can you please clarify?

Comment: Hey, no that would not work. That expression would not match `{a}{}{}{a}`, which is a bad prefix (we cannot continue this word to a trace in P2, since the condition that between two a's, b should always hold fails for any continuation of this prefix). We need the `(b and not a)*` part to match bad prefixes such as `{a}{b}{b}{}{a}`. So it could be that after reading the first a, the condition that b has to hold is met for a few characters (the `{b}{b}` part), but then becomes violated (at `{}`).

Comment: We need the `(true)*` part for bad prefixes such as `{a}{b}{b}{}{b}{b}{a}`. So the `{}` matches `(not a and not b)`, but then afterwards we see a few b's before we reach the closing a. So the second `{b}{b}` block would match the `(true)*`.

Comment: Thanks. So, `(true)*` can correspond to any number of characters i.e it can represent one `{b}` or two `{b}{b}` , am I right? And I have Christeil Baier book Model checking , and i have checked Aachen's videos , any other resource you can mention that would help to understand this concept, it would be really helpful

Comment: Right, `true` matches any single character, e.g. it could match `{}` or `{a}` or `{b}` or `{a,b}`. And then the `*` means zero or more repetitions of that pattern, so `(true)*` would match any finite sequence, e.g. the empty sequence ` ` (length zero), every sequence of length one, such as `{}` or `{a}` or `{b}` or `{a,b}`, every sequence of length two, so `{}{}`, `{}{a}`, `{a}{a}`, and so on. I'm not aware of other resources on that topic unfortunately.

Comment: Hi , i have one more question. `Consider the set AP = {A,B} of atomic propositions.The property : **A and B alternate infinitely often** `. Can you please tell what property it is ? I think it holds true for Liveness.Can you clarify ?

Comment: and for the formula `phi = (a V -b )` (a or not b) , it refers to the symbols`{} {a}` ? but `phi = (a Λ -b )` refers to the symbols `{a}`? Am i correct ?

Comment: Right, that property is a Liveness property, because every finite word over the power set of AP can be continued to a trace that meets the property. More formally, for every finite word w in Pow(AP)*, the trace w{A}{B}{A}{B}{A}{B}... = w({A}{B})^omega meets the property.

Comment: The formula `(a or not b)` is satisfied by `{}` (because it contains no b), `{a}` (because it contains a) and also `{a,b}` (because it contains `a`, recall that for "or" at least one side has to be satisfied, so in this case the `not b` part is not satisfied, but because the `a` part is satisfied, the whole formula is still true).  The formula is not satisfied by `{b}` (because it does not contain a and also does not not contain b). The formula `(a and not b)` is satisfied only by `{a}`, correct.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot . I have a few more questions like these , and some of which I can't ask in the comments and I am constrained by time because I have exams tomorrow. Is there a way to contact you digitally where i can share the questions ? It would be really helpful.